# Limit of real function, theoretical exercise

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-verification

I'm a freshman in mathematics and this is my exercise:

> Prove that for function $f:\langle -a,a\rangle\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow\langle0,+\infty\rangle$ so that is
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)}\right)=2$$
>   is also
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=1.$$

I've tried to solve this problem from the Cauchy's definition of limit
$$(\forall \varepsilon>0) (\exists\delta>0) (\forall x \in \langle -a,a\rangle\setminus\{0\})\qquad (0< \lvert x-0\rvert  < \delta) \implies \Big( \Big| f(x)+\frac{1}{f(x)} \Big| < \varepsilon \Big)$$

by trying to get $\Big|f(x)-1\Big|<\varepsilon $ but I got that just in case $f(x)\in\langle0,1]$.

Any thoughts on solving the problem this way or I should use another approach?

Comment: What is the point to use $\langle$ to instead of the conventional $($?

Comment: Isn't that just point of personal preference?

Comment: No: the choice between round brackets and angle brackets as a notation for inner products is a matter of personal preference, but angle brackets are not used as a notation for open intervals.

Comment: In Croatia, we usually use angle brackets for open intervals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice that to prove $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$, it is equivalent to show that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $0$, we have 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1.$$

Let $\{x_n\}$ be any sequence converging to zero (for $\{x_n\}$ being contained in the domain of $f$, $\{x_n\} \subset (-a, a) \backslash\{0\}$). By condition, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(f(x_n) + \frac{1}{f(x_n)}\right) = 2,$$
which implies that the sequence $\left\{f(x_n) + \frac{1}{f(x_n)}\right\}$ is bounded above. Since $f(x_n) > 0$ for each $n$, it follows that $0 < f(x_n) < f(x_n) + \frac{1}{f(x_n)}$, hence the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ is also bounded. By Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem, $\{f(x_n)\}$ contains a convergent sequence, say, $\{f(x_{n_k})\}$.

Suppose that $\lim_{k \to \infty} f(x_{n_k}) = c \geq 0$. Clearly $c > 0$, otherwise 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(f(x_{n_k}) + \frac{1}{f(x_{n_k})}\right) = 2 \tag{1}$$ would be violated. Therefore $\{1/f(x_{n_k})\}$ also converges with its limit $\frac{1}{c}$. Hence, $(1)$ gives that
$$c + \frac{1}{c} = 2.$$
Solving this for $c$, we obtain $c = 1$.

Now for any convergent subsequence $\{f(x_{n_m})\}$ of $\{f(x_n)\}$, similar argument as above gives that its limit must be $1$. Therefore $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x_n) = 1$, and the proof is complete.

Comment: So if every convergent subsequence $f(x_{n_k}))$ of $f(x_n)$ is convergent and has the same limit, then $f(x_n)$ must be convergent?

Comment: Yes, this is a sufficient and necessary condition for convergent sequences.

Comment: Can the downvoters explain why is it?

Comment: I understand that intuitively, but I'm not perfectly clear with it.
Could the explanation be:
If we assume the opposite, that $f(x_n)$ does not converge then it would have two convergent subsequences with different limits which is a contradiction.

Comment: The direction that all the convergent subsequences of a convergent sequence have the same limit is obvious (try $\varepsilon$-$N$ argument). For the other direction, try proof by contradiction by assuming two convergent subsequences with two distinct limits, then the original sequence cannot be convergent. It is also clear if taking upper and lower limits point of view.